# How to Create Filtered Lookup using Multiple Field Values

Tags: 2010, infopath

I currently have a List with thousands of entries.  This List is used to manage requests for documentation purposes.  Currently, the List form (customized in InfoPath) has a single line of text field for the user to enter the document title.  We want to eliminate the manual entry.

We have a separate Data List which contains all of our thousands of document titles.  This List contains other metadata like Business Area and Document Type.  I want to create a Document Title Lookup field in our current List Request Form which will lookup the values of the document title in the other List.  This is easy enough to do.  However, I want to be able to filter this drop-down field based on the selection of the Business Area and Document Type that the user selects on the Request Form (these fields already exist on the Request Form).

I am struggling on how to do this.  i have walked through many articles on implementing cascading drop-downs and filtered lookups with no success.  The issue seems to be that I am using multiple filters.

Does anyone have any ideas or has implemented a similar solution?

Thanks,
Mike